# What rewards can I earn during the Decoration Events?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I learned today about the Decoration Events in Tiny Death Star.

I know I have to wait for or summon a *Decorator Droid* during an event to decorate a floor, but what rewards can I earn by using this droid in all the events?

would the rewards be worth summoning all droids at the 5 bucks cost or would the value of the reward be less? Assuming the rewards are a one off and there will be no other way to get them.

[image]

Comment: The first reward are come coins, I don't know how much exactly, the next one I think it's unlocking a droid

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an event that is now over.

Comment: This event has restarted. Best not to close topics unless actually neccesary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10 Floors - Credits (I got 5000 second time, not sure what bonus was the first time)

20 Floors - Boba Fett (Holiday Special)

35 Floors - Panna Citi Medicines (Service Level) gets built immediately on top of your Death Star (note that price of next level will go up, so if you have almost enough money to start building a level - it may be wise to wait, start your level and after that get your reward for decorations).

after that you get 1 bux for every decorated floor.

Occasionally Emperor Palpatine shows up to rip off all your decorations. After that you have to start all over again.
I managed to get 35+ floors decorated in 1 sitting (without exiting game).

You can build more than one Panna Citi levels this way - I have two at the moment.

Also, Holiday Boba unlocks scene in Panna Citi.

Comment: Just happened to me on the iOS version.  Exiting the game was not the trigger, I had 45 plus decorated floors. And, had exited the game multiple times.  Perhaps Panna Citi Medicines is meant to be like Starbucks . . .

Comment: Seeing there are only 24 residential floors now (120 max residents) and 4 x 10 x 3 job vacancies (not counting the ones provided by the number of Panna City Medicines you may have), I suspect the Panna City Medicines shops are not here to stay. They'll probably be removed once the decoration event is over. This is just my speculation though. It would suck if the devs remove something that we all worked so hard to get...

Comment: Seems unlikely they'll get removed. The bug never removed them. So, assuming that it worked the same way as the final implementation, Panna City Meds is probably here to stay.

Answer (score 5):

You will get some coins for decorating 10 floors, a special edition Boba Fett for 20 and a new shop Panna City Medicines (under Service) for 35.

Not sure if the game was buggy or it was designed in such a way, but I had to start from 0 decorations again on a new day, when it stated I only had 23 days left. It's a pain in the arse having to start from scratch every day... So I would advise you have at least built 35 floors (including Imperial levels) before going all out to decorate 35 floors by using bux to get decorator droids. Not sure if there are any rewards beyond the 35 floors.

You can't decorate the same floor twice, nor can you decorate one under construction.

I learnt it the hard way but there's absolutely no use saving up any decorator droids, hoping to get a headstart in a new day. My 5 saved droids disappeared with the coming of a new day, but at least the very first decorator droid that u can summon for 0 bux gets reset everyday too.

Comment: It's too soon to see, but my current assumption is maybe decorating imperial levels triggered the emperors wrath! Testing it without decorating any to see if this is true.